# Env variable invalid interpolation format for "required variable is missing a value"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, substitution, string-interpolation

I have this `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox:latest
    entrypoint: ''
    environment:
      - bar=${foo:-baz}
    command: 
      - "/bin/sh" 
      - "-c" 
      - "echo $$bar"
```

that I'm running this way:

```sh
docker-compose up && docker-compose down
```

output:

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network interpolation-poblem_default      Created
 ⠿ Container interpolation-poblem-busybox-1  Created
Attaching to interpolation-poblem-busybox-1
interpolation-poblem-busybox-1  | baz
interpolation-poblem-busybox-1 exited with code 0
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Container interpolation-poblem-busybox-1  Removed
 ⠿ Network interpolation-poblem_default      Removed
```

It works properly - `foo` is substituted with `baz` that is echoed by: `/bin/sh -c "echo $bar"`

```
interpolation-poblem-busybox-1  | baz
```

but when I change `bar=${foo:-baz}` to `bar=${foo:?mandatory}`

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox:latest
    entrypoint: ''
    environment:
      - bar=${foo:?mandatory}
    command: 
      - "/bin/sh" 
      - "-c" 
      - "echo $$bar"
```

and run again:

```sh
docker-compose up && docker-compose down
```

I'm getting the output:

> invalid interpolation format for services.busybox.environment.[]: "required variable foo is missing a value: mandatory". You may need to escape any $ with another $

The error info is a bit confusing, it sounds to me as if literary the  `mandatory` string was expected. But even if I run:

```sh
foo=mandatory docker-compose up && docker-compose down
```

output:

```
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container interpolation-poblem-busybox-1  Created
Attaching to interpolation-poblem-busybox-1
interpolation-poblem-busybox-1  | mandatory
interpolation-poblem-busybox-1 exited with code 0
invalid interpolation format for services.busybox.environment.[]: "required variable foo is missing a value: mandatory". You may need to escape any $ with another $
```

note the output as above has:

```
interpolation-poblem-busybox-1  | mandatory
```

but lacks of:

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Container interpolation-poblem-busybox-1  Removed
 ⠿ Network interpolation-poblem_default      Removed
```

that was present in the example of `bar=${foo:-baz}` when everything worked well. I looks that the command `docker-compose down` did not do any job and in fact running:

```sh
docker ps -a
```

shows the output:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
3b7c0a9caa63   busybox:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'echo $b…"   3 minutes ago   Exited (0) 3 minutes ago             interpolation-poblem-busybox-1
```

so the container `interpolation-poblem-busybox-1` was not removed.

Trying to take it down again by:

```sh
docker-compose down
```

gives the same output:

> invalid interpolation format for services.busybox.environment.[]: "required variable foo is missing a value: mandatory". You may need to escape any $ with another $

Without the container being removed.

Even running:

```sh
docker-compose ps
```

generates the same output error.

as per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

> Similarly, the following syntax allows you to specify mandatory variables:
>
> - `${VARIABLE:?err}` exits with an error message containing `err` if `VARIABLE` is unset or empty in the environment.
> - `${VARIABLE?err}` exits with an error message containing `err` if `VARIABLE` is unset in the environment.

the syntax of:

```yaml
    environment:
      - bar=${foo:?mandatory}
```

seems to be correct.

Host's system:

```sh
docker --version
```

> Docker version 20.10.13, build a224086

[Docker Engine release notes v20.10](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#201013) - however I see that the [release on github is v19.03.14](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v19.03.14)

```sh
docker-compose --version
```

> Docker Compose version v2.3.3

[Docker Compose release notes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/) - There is no version v2.3.3 there, the highest is [1.29.2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1292), but at [github releases has v2.3.3](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.3.3)

```sh
hostnamectl | grep Kernel
```

> Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-171-generic

I guess that problem may be related to the `Docker version 20.10.13, build a224086` that I recently updated by Ubuntu prompt and not checking off the Docker box from the list of choice.

There is no `docker` version v20.x at the [Compatibility matrix](https://docs.master.dockerproject.org/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/)

I could not find similar list for the `docker-compose` command.

However none of the versions I use are tagged with `dev`, `alpha`, `beta`, `rc`, `nb` so I would expect that I should run pretty stable release but maybe I am wrong.

Could anyone provide the solution - how to use:

```yaml
    environment:
      - bar=${foo:?mandatory}
```

without any problems as described above?

The issues about interpolation do not clarify what I did wrong:

`docker-compose` [is:issue is:open invalid interpolation](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+invalid+interpolation)

It would be helpful If someone could share a link to an official document that describes the release policy of `docker` and `docker-compose` including their road-map and possible info about their period of support plus the clarification on stable releases naming convention.

I only found [this roadmap](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/projects/1) that says not too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `foo=mandatory docker-compose up && docker-compose down`, you are running `foo=mandatory docker-compose up` and then `docker-compose down`, which means the `docker-compose down` is not receiving that variable, and thus giving you that error when trying to read the template.

If you run `foo=mandatory docker-compose up && foo=mandatory docker-compose down`, it will work. You may also export the variable so you don't need to pass it twice:

```sh
export foo=mandatory
# now foo=mandatory will be passed to all commands after the export
docker-compose up && docker-compose down
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works well. `foo=mandatory docker-compose up && foo=mandatory docker-compose down` works too. But why `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose ps` commands  require `foo` to be set? What for? I did not expect that and searched everywhere but the right place for the problem. Perhaps they call a `docker-compose.yaml` parser for whatever reason and if that parser is not supplied with a variable then returns an error that is somehow a problem even the intention is to take a container down.

Comment: Yes, `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose ps` both parse your `docker-compose.yml` I'd guess it's probably needed because of grace periods and dependency orders which may be specified in your compose.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's oftentimes bullshit. There are scenarios where it could matter, though, so they are playing it safe. Sometimes I don't have these guys around but then I will just set dummies in down...